# How to make a generic function for enumValues<T> in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics, enums

I struggle with providing a type as parameter for a procedure that uses the `enumValues<MyEnum>()` function.
Got it to work with `reified` but using `inline` functions all the way is no option for me.

```kotlin
    fun <T: Enum<Trait>> traits(
        selectionState: SnapshotStateMap<Trait, Boolean>
    ) {
        val chunks = enumValues<T>().toList().chunked(5)
        chunks.forEach {
            Row {
                it.forEach {
                    TraitIcon(it, selectionState)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My enums all derive from `enum class Trait`. So in fact I want to pass `enum class TraitFoo: Trait`, `enum class TraitBar: Trait` and so on into the function.

> Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.

Is the compile error I receive here. Any idea of solving this? I am somewhat confused why this is not working.

Looking at the implementation of `enumValues`:

```kotlin
public inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> enumValues(): Array<T>
```

I see it uses `reified`. That does mean the type has to be known at compile time. Therefore I can not pass a generic but need to pass an explicit type? Is that the issue?

If yes - is there another way to achieve this rather than using `reified` ?

Comment: So something like `inline fun <reified T> traits(...) where T : Enum<T>, T : Trait { ... }` would not work for you? Note the where-clause is because I assume `Trait` is not already an `Enum<Trait>` (i.e. it's not declared as `enum class Trait { ... }`). If `Trait` already is an enum then I don't understand the purpose of `T` to begin with.

Comment: You say your enum classes inherit from another enum class, but that’s not possible. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Tenfour04 What is your source that this shouldn't be possible? Please take a look here: https://github.com/xetra11/CK3-Workbench/blob/472dc82310795a442a5fdc67591093d8e950b322/src/main/kotlin/com/github/xetra11/ck3workbench/module/character/TraitSelection.kt#L37 - this is where I am declaring the inheritance and also am using it throughout the code having covariances with `Trait`.

Comment: @Slaw You're approach is giving me `Type argument is not within its bounds.
Expected:
Enum<TypeVariable(T)>
Found:
T`

Comment: @xetra11 In that code `Trait` and `LeveledTrait` are not `enum class`, but `interface`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov ah crap you're right. Sorry I kept it in my head as enum inheritance even though I realized it with an interface. My bad.

Comment: @xetra11 You can see a compiling version of Slaw's comment here https://pl.kotl.in/0hnbVoz97. Of course, it can't use "real" `Row`, `SnapeshotStateMap`, etc. but it still should work; if it doesn't, edit your question to include the code you use and where the error happens.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov can you explain `where T : Enum<T>, T : Trait`? Why does it need to say that T is an enum and also deriving from `Trait`? Why isn't it sufficent just to have `where T: Trait` ?

Comment: Because you're attempting to use `enumValues<T>()`, which unsurprisingly requires the `T` to be an `Enum<T>`. You also want your enum to implement `Trait`. So it needs to be bounded by both. At least, that's how I understood your requirements.

Comment: Ahhh @Slaw ok now all make sense. I need to get rid of the thought that `Trait` is an enum. That was the sticking point here. Thanks a heap! Also feel free to define a full answer for acceptance

Comment: @Tenfour04 yea I clarified that throughout the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to use `T` in your function as if it's a real type then it must be reified. And in order for a type parameter to be reified it must be part of an inline function. So you're going to need an inline function.

The next bit is figuring out the generics. You currently have:

```kotlin
<T : Enum<Trait>>
```

That means, due to the nature of enums, that `T` can't possibly be anything other than `Trait`. However, you have since clarified that `Trait` is *not* an enum but is actually an interface that's *implemented* by various enum classes. So what you really want is `T` to be bounded by both `Enum<T>` and `Trait`.

Given all this, I believe what you're looking for is the following:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> traits(
    selectionState: SnapshotTraitMap<Trait, Boolean>
) where T : Enum<T>, T : Trait {
    val chunks = enumValues<T>().toList().chunked(5)
    chunks.forEach {
        Row {
            it.forEach {
                TraitIcon(it, selectionState)
            }
        }
    }
}
```